# Calculation with variable doesnt work but does if using hardcoded value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to plot a line to the chart if the following condition is met (example).

When using the variable output (based on math/calulation) from 'rangeLow' it **doesnt work**:

```
rangeLow = open-(open/100*25) // assuming open equals 40000, the result is 30000 per my math.
bool isSupport = open >= rangeLow  // throws no errors but lines not meeting the condition gets printed to chart.
```

When using a hardcoded value instead, it **works**.

```
rangeLow = 30000
bool isSupport = open >= rangeLow     // works when printing a line to chart. Lines not meeting the condition dont get printed.
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified the type  and value of rangeLow match what you expect?

Order-of-operations is occasionally surprising

Comment: I got no idea what you are asking me. Sorry. Since it doesnt throw an error, I would have expected the syntax is OK.

Comment: Can you print the value for rangeLow after you calculate it?  The syntax is likely fine, but depending on the language and assumptions, it is ambiguous whether `open-(open/100*25)` equals `open-(open/(100*25))` or `open-((open/100)*25)`.  The two possibilities will give different filters.  See also https://kodify.net/tradingview/operators/order-operations-pine/

Comment: Thanks I get the point and I tried any possible combination. I am braindead and tired. Even I simplify it and do open-10000 I dont get it respected.

Comment: Appreciate your attempt to shed the lights - even though I am still sitting in the dark. I honestly got no clue whats wrong and read the article from each direction twice now.

Per the article my first attempt was correct, even open-((open/100)*25) should be fine but it remains wrong.

Comment: You dont want me to beg you, right? If you know how this is to solve. I appreciate HELP in cleartext. Thanks.

Comment: I've never used Pine, so I can't give you a solid answer. I can only suggest some things to try: 1) Add more detail to your question about things you have tried. 2) Provide sample cases where the filter (isSupport) doesn't work the way you expect. 3) Print the value of "rangeLow". 4) Experiment with explicit parentheses in the calculation of "open" and of "isSupport", and update the question with the results. 5) Check that "open" and the other variables aren't otherwise used as reserved words or other variables in scope.

Comment: Hey Sarah, thanks for getting back. The math is working. 
The issue here only is, that whether I take the output as it is, convert to string, to number to regardless what, its not accepted. If I put in the plain number as hardcoded value instead, its working. So its not related to the function I got. Its related to the format/type and there is no way to, regardless of conversion I do, to get it accepted. Thanks anyway.